# Sequelize : Two belongsToMany associate the same table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, sequelize.js

My user table need associate to two ManyToMany model.

that is user's collection and user's history,
the join table's column is the same (id, userId, albumId).

the two join table auto created by sequelize, but when I use User.addAlbum(), how can I add associate to specific table.

```
models.user.belongsToMany(models.album, { through: 'album_collections' })
models.user.belongsToMany(models.album, { through: 'album_play_record' })
```

now it will add to album_collections, how can I add new association to album_play_record

Comment: Welcome on SO. If you want add some details to question - edit it. Adding information in comments is not correct (on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new model named `'album_play_record'` and associate it in `belongsToMany`

```
const AlbumPlayRecord = sequelize.define('album_play_record', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    description: Sequelize.TEXT
});

models.user.belongsToMany(models.album, { through: models.album_play_record });
models.album_play_record.belongsTo(models.xxx);
```